# URL rewriting must be activated manually for my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting

I am creating a Wordpress plugin which create pages (with `get_header()`, `get_footer()` and `get_sidebar()`) for searching through an API.

Of course, I have defined some rules for URL rewriting like this:

```
function init() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_rule('my_plugin/(.+)/results?', 'index.php?my_plugin=results&data=$matches[1]', 'top');
    ...
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

This function is called with this line in the constructor of my plugin:

```
add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
```

The plugin works perfectly but I need to activate manually URL rewriting in **Settings > Permalinks** in my Admin Dashboard. I need only to select one option: *Day and name*, *Month and name*, *Numeric*,... (whatever).

The problem is that when I install the plugin on a new Wordpress with Permalinks disable (*Default*), I am getting always a **404 error**. This will only work if I activate manually Permalinks.
(I know this is done by the *.htaccess*).

**Is there is a way to bypass this or to activate automatically Permalinks through my plugin ?

Other good solution is welcome.**

I hope my question is clear.
Thank you.

Comment: `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` - This is an extremely expensive line of code for every page load.

Comment: I look at this: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules).Rules are defined in my *init* function but I have a function for the activation plugin. Can I move the URL rewriting code ?

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule()` can live outside of a callback function. It doesn't have dependencies on any hook or callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I create a plugin that needs permalinks enabled i check on the plugin activation and if its not set i display a message for the user:

```
// Add Check if permalinks are set on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'is_permalink_activate' );
function is_permalink_activate() {
    //add notice if user needs to enable permalinks
    if (! get_option('permalink_structure') )
        add_action('admin_notices', 'permalink_structure_admin_notice');
}

function permalink_structure_admin_notice(){
    echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>Please Make sure to enable <a href="options-permalink.php">Permalinks</a>.</p></div>';
}
```

Comment: This is my preferred approach. Plugins should never brute force change blog settings without the user's consent.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a better idea. I try this!

Comment: Thanks for the `get_option('permalink_structure')`!

Answer (score 0):

I found the code.

```
modify_permalinks('/%postname%/','','');
function modify_permalinks($permalink_structure, $category_base, $tag_base){
    global $wp_rewrite;

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/misc.php');

    # get paths

    $home_path = get_home_path();
    $iis7_permalinks = iis7_supports_permalinks();

    # set the structure

    $permalink_structure = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', '/' . $permalink_structure);
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure($permalink_structure);

    $category_base = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', '/' . $category_base);
    $wp_rewrite->set_category_base($category_base);

    $tag_base = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', '/' . $tag_base);
    $wp_rewrite->set_tag_base($tag_base);

    # check if there is a file to rewrite

    if ( $iis7_permalinks ) {
        if ( ( ! file_exists($home_path . 'web.config') && win_is_writable($home_path) ) || win_is_writable($home_path . 'web.config') )
            $writable = true;
        else
            $writable = false;
    } else {
        if ( ( ! file_exists($home_path . '.htaccess') && is_writable($home_path) ) || is_writable($home_path . '.htaccess') )
            $writable = true;
        else
            $writable = false;
    }

    # flush the rules

    update_option('rewrite_rules', FALSE);
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules($writable);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the issue?

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to change user Permalinks setting if it is already activated. I have an idea: apply this if there is no *.htaccess* and put a default setting for Permalinks but it not very clean. Any other idea ?